# How ot get bounce rate count in numbers in google analytic report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am using google analytic to log visits on my website.
I am getting bounce rate in percentage. Can I see bounce rate in exact numbers in a page at google analytic.

Comment: I have no idea where they are in the standard reports, but you can select bounces as a metric when you create a custom report. This isn't on topic, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the raw number of Bounces from a Custom report.

In Google Analytics, select 'Customisation' at the top of the page. Then click '+ New Custom Report'.

You can select 'Bounces' from the metrics list, and you'll need at least one Dimension; I recommend 'Landing Page'. You may wish to add additional metrics for comparison.

See my report here: [Custom Report Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u4eD.png)

Click 'Save' and you'll have a report showing the raw number of Bounces for each Landing Page on your site. At the top is a summary across the whole site.

If you used the same setup as me, you should be able to see that the Bounce Rate is equal to Bounces / Sessions. This is how it's always calculated in Google Analytics.

Comment: changed log page view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026099/google-analytics-record-page-view-though-ajax-call