# Google analytics record page view though ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I am logging page view through ajax action when my inner page content gets loaded. Issue is bounce rate data is not updated (always 0%)

Default ga page view record logged  from footer.

```
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

After this I am executing code to load inner page content then logging page view for this action.

```
function gapPageView(hash)
{
   ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': hash});
}
```

Page view entries are recorded successfully in google analytic and can seen in All pages report.
/
/step1

May time I visited same page and closed tab. removed browser cookies and open new session.
But there is not data change in bounce rate of step1.

Please help me understand if I am missing something here.

Comment: If all your visitors have at minumum 2 interactions (one from the pageload and one from the ajax call) the bounce rate will be 0% since bounces are users with just one interaction.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you're firing two separate page views within the same page, to check that it's loaded properly.

Bounce Rate is the percentage of Sessions which Bounced. If you're looking at a page level, you only count as a Session if you arrived here first, and you only count as a Bounce if you began here, and then interacted no further (which will likely only register 30 minutes later, as it will hang on to the hope that you may interact again).

This means that you can only count as a Bounce on the first page of the site that you saw, so it's impossible for somebody to bounce on the second page view.

Meanwhile the first page view will only be treated as a Bounce if there is no further interaction. Since you fire another page view almost immediately, it's almost impossible for a user to bounce on the first page view. They'd have to have avoided the second trigger somehow, such as because that part of the site didn't load, or perhaps that they closed the browser at the exact right time. This is unlikely to happen unless you have a lot of traffic to your site.

Comment: I am triggering the virtual pageview at end of all the ajax calls & after page load, so if user dont interact with the page at all the bounce rate should be attributed to the virtual pageview as it the last page user visited but due to some reason the bounce rate is shown 0% which is the problem.

I want the virtual pageview to have correct bounce rate attributed to it

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of the word 'bounce'.
A 'Bounce' is where a user interacted once only.

A page's Bounce Rate is the proportion of visits that began on that page, and then did nothing else.

Since the virtual page view is triggered inside an actual page, it's nearly impossible to bounce on the virtual page.

I think what you're referring to may be Exits, and the Exit Rate. An Exit is the final interaction in a Session.